# Rails:Best way to update multiple models when changes are made to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Rails 4.2 app which has model `AutomaticMatch` that stores the matching score between an `Account` (user profile) and an `Assignment`. There is a has_many relationship between `Account` and `AutomaticMatch`,the same for `Assignments`. I have a number of methods stored in a helper that calculate that score:

```
#Calculates the total compatibility score between an account and an assignment
#Returns a decimal which is the percent of compatibility

def total_score_assign(account,assign)
  score_categories = score_categories_assign(account,assign)
  sum = 0
  categories = (assign.skills.map{|h| h.category}).uniq

  score_categories.each do |k,v|
   sum += v
  end

  total = sum / categories.size
end
```

So,I would like to trigger the calculation of scores and creation of corresponding  `AutomaticMatch` db records before an `Assignment` is saved and recalculation + update `AutomaticMatch` records whenever an `Assignment` or an `Account` is updated. 
My question is, what is the best approach to implement this, given the fact that I should perform CRUD operations on different models whenever something changes in another model? 
 After some research, I discovered the following approaches:

- applying Strategy pattern and making a Service class where I perform those operations
- using ActiveRecord callbacks and perform those operations in the AutomaticMatch model
- using Observers

Now I'm quite confused since I don't know whether there is a Rails way to do this and which of the above is the one,if any. This is my first big project in Rails and I don't yet know much about problems and practices specific to big apps,so I would appreciate greatly an insightful opinion.

Comment: #2 [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks)

Comment: @daslicious I was looking into the same issue as the one described here, would you explain a bit why the AR callbacks are a better choice? Also, are there any other options than the ones outlined here?

Comment: That would be great @daslicious

Comment: thats the only thing i've used to do what you're describing. you mentioned the rails way and that would make AR callbacks the choice since AR is a part of rails. you want something to happen before a save which is what `before_save` does. although you might want to hold off on creating the `AutomaticMatch` until `after_save`

Answer (score 1):

A really cool project that provides pub/sub and allows a service class to respond to messages from various application events is wisper: https://github.com/krisleech/wisper - You can register listeners and respond to notifications with service objects. I found it to be a really useful way to avoid dependencies and keep code more organized. It's also very easy to push jobs to background processes to avoid blocking etc. The following is a modified excerpt from an article that can be found here: http://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/the-publish-subscribe-pattern-on-rails

```
# app/listener/feed_listener.rb
class FeedListener
  def post_create(post)
    Services::FeedService.create!(post)
  end
end

# app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb
# corresponds to the publisher in the previous figure
class Api::V1::PostsController < Api::V1::ApiController
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      # Publish event about post creation for any interested listeners
      publish(:post_create, @post)
      render_created(@post)
    end 
  end
end

# config/initializers/wisper.rb
Wisper.subscribe(FeedListener.new)
```

This is the best way I have found to keep separation of concerns, compartmentalize service code and keep my models and controllers from getting too chubby.

Comment: So, I should have a listener that subscribes to both `Assignment` and `Account` and create new instances of AutomaticMatch in that listener?

Comment: some of this would depend on how heavy a process the matching "algorithm" is.  if it takes time to process you would want to have a listener that can run that service waiting for notifications that contain objects with the data that it needs to process to do it's job. I think you would want an AutomaticMatchListener class that will hang out and wait for a controller to publish a message when Assignment and Account objects are created or updated so it can process the creation and updating of "automatic matches".

Comment: It is quite heavy so I will try this approach.Thanks a lot!